# read temperature sensor value on intel edison using python mraa

Tags: python, sensors, temperature, intel-edison

I have configured temperature sensor with intel edison. I am trying to read temperature sensor values using following python code

```
import mraa
import time
import sys
import math

tmp = mraa.Gpio(2)
tmp.dir(mraa.DIR_IN)
i=0
while i<100:
    print "Let's talk about Temperature  %s." % tmp.read()
    time. sleep(3)
    i+=1
exit()
```

But this code is return always 0 as reading value.

I am new to intel edison and python. So any help will be appreciating. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

mraa is a low level skeleton library for I/O communication. In case of a basic analog sensor it will do the job, but I would recommend you to use upm instead.

```
import time
import pyupm_grove as grove

# Create the temperature sensor object using AIO pin 0
temp = grove.GroveTemp(0)

for i in range(0, 10):
    celsius = temp.value()
    fahrenheit = celsius * 9.0/5.0 + 32.0;
    print "%d degrees Celsius, or %d degrees Fahrenheit" \
        % (celsius, fahrenheit)
    time.sleep(1)

# Delete the temperature sensor object
del temp
```

If it does n't work, you may need to update the libraries

```
echo "src mraa-upm http://iotdk.intel.com/repos/3.0/intelgalactic/opkg/i586" > /etc/opkg/mraa-upm.conf
opkg update
opkg upgrade libmraa0
opkg upgrade upm
```

Comment: What in case of digital DHT11 which uses one wire communication mechanism?